# SQL grouping interescting/overlapping rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I have the following table in Postgres that has overlapping data in the two columns `a_sno` and `b_sno`.

```
create table data
( a_sno integer not null,  
  b_sno integer not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (a_sno,b_sno)
);

insert into data (a_sno,b_sno) values
  ( 4, 5 )
, ( 5, 4 )
, ( 5, 6 )
, ( 6, 5 )
, ( 6, 7 )
, ( 7, 6 )
, ( 9, 10)
, ( 9, 13)
, (10, 9 )
, (13, 9 )
, (10, 13)
, (13, 10)
, (10, 14)
, (14, 10)
, (13, 14)
, (14, 13)
, (11, 15)
, (15, 11);
```

As you can see from the first 6 rows data values  4,5,6 and 7 in the two columns intersects/overlaps that need to partitioned to a group. Same goes for rows 7-16 and rows 17-18 which will be labeled as group 2 and 3 respectively.

The resulting output should look like this:

```
group | value
------+------
1     | 4
1     | 5
1     | 6
1     | 7
2     | 9
2     | 10
2     | 13
2     | 14
3     | 11
3     | 15
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that all pairs exists in their mirrored combination as well `(4,5)` and `(5,4)`. But the following solutions work without mirrored dupes just as well.

#### Simple case

All connections can be lined up in a **single ascending sequence** and complications like I added in the [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55cc22/4) are not possible, we can use this solution without duplicates in the rCTE:

I start by getting minimum `a_sno` per group, with the minimum associated `b_sno`:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a_sno) AS grp
     , a_sno, min(b_sno) AS b_sno
FROM   data d
WHERE  a_sno < b_sno
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 FROM data
   WHERE  b_sno = d.a_sno
   AND    a_sno < b_sno
   )
GROUP  BY a_sno;
```

This only needs a single query level since a window function can be built on an aggregate:

- [Get the distinct sum of a joined table column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13169367/get-the-distinct-sum-of-a-joined-table-column/13169627#13169627)

Result:

```
grp  a_sno  b_sno
1    4      5
2    9      10
3    11     15
```

I avoid branches and duplicated (multiplicated) rows - potentially *much* more expensive with long chains. I use `ORDER BY b_sno LIMIT 1` in a correlated subquery to make this fly in a recursive CTE.

- [Create a unique index on a non-unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171623/create-a-unique-index-on-a-non-unique-column/29172960#29172960)

Key to performance is a matching index, which is already present provided by the PK constraint `PRIMARY KEY (a_sno,b_sno)`: not the other way round <strike>`(b_sno, a_sno)`</strike>:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/27493/3684)

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY d.a_sno) AS grp
        , a_sno, min(b_sno) AS b_sno  -- the smallest one
   FROM   data d
   WHERE  a_sno < b_sno
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM data
      WHERE  b_sno = d.a_sno
      AND    a_sno < b_sno
      )
   GROUP  BY a_sno
   )

, cte AS (
   SELECT grp, b_sno AS sno FROM t

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.grp
       , (SELECT b_sno  -- correlated subquery
          FROM   data
          WHERE  a_sno = c.sno
          AND    a_sno < b_sno
          ORDER  BY b_sno
          LIMIT  1)
   FROM   cte  c
   WHERE  c.sno IS NOT NULL
   )
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE  sno IS NOT NULL   -- eliminate row with NULL
UNION  ALL               -- no duplicates
SELECT grp, a_sno FROM t
ORDER  BY grp, sno;
```

#### Less simple case

All nodes can be reached in ascending order with one or more branches from the root (smallest `sno`).

This time, get *all* greater `sno` and de-duplicate nodes that may be visited multiple times with `UNION` at the end:

```
WITH RECURSIVE t AS (
   SELECT rank() OVER (ORDER BY d.a_sno) AS grp
        , a_sno, b_sno  -- get all rows for smallest a_sno
   FROM   data d
   WHERE  a_sno < b_sno
   AND    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 FROM data
      WHERE  b_sno = d.a_sno
      AND    a_sno < b_sno
      )
   )   
, cte AS (
   SELECT grp, b_sno AS sno FROM t

   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.grp, d.b_sno
   FROM   cte  c
   JOIN   data d ON d.a_sno = c.sno
                AND d.a_sno < d.b_sno  -- join to all connected rows
   )
SELECT grp, sno FROM cte
UNION                     -- eliminate duplicates
SELECT grp, a_sno FROM t  -- add first rows
ORDER  BY grp, sno;
```

Unlike the first solution, we don't get a last row with NULL here (caused by the correlated subquery).

Both should perform very well - especially with long chains / many branches. Result as desired:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/55cc22/4) (with added rows to demonstrate difficulty).

#### Undirected graph

If there are local minima that cannot be reached from the root with ascending traversal, the above solutions won't work. Consider [Farhęg's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29737591/939860) in this case.

Comment: a great answer with great explanations, I especially like such these explanations which makes SO much better

Comment: and also the clever point with this answer is the recursive cte does not involve in a loop so there is no need to use a cycle flag and path array

Comment: @Farhęg: However, I just realized that I might have over-optimized with LIMIT 1. The query might miss members of the group, depending on the actual characteristics of the data ... adding a corrective ...

Comment: Erwin, you solution works better than the other 2 solutions from a performance standpoint. However, only on small datasets upto 50K rows. I am applying this logic on a 2M rows table and the performance of the query is very bad. Is there a way to improve the performance? Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @bogeyman: Which of my answers fits your scenario? I have made assumptions and provided multiple answers because the question didn't provide all the details. The cardinalities you mention should be *in the question*. For performance optimization, you need to provide full details. [Consider guidelines here.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) Update your question with missing details or - if that would change the nature of the question - start a new one. Finally, if my answer works best, why is the other one still accepted?

Comment: Erwin, Thank you. Marking your question as answer.I had selected the previous one as it was the first one that seemed to work initially. But after several tries I found the first two solutions not able to handle more than 3000 rows. The code that I am using is your "Less Simple case".

Comment: Erwin, Never mind. I tried your first solution. This works like a charm. I didn't pay much attention to your note "Unlike the first solution, we don't get a last row with NULL here ". That was the problem. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I want to say another way, it may be useful, you can do it in 2 steps:

**1.** take the `max(sno)` per each group:

```
  select q.sno,
         row_number() over(order by q.sno) gn
  from(
    select distinct d.a_sno sno
    from data d
    where not exists (
      select b_sno
      from data
      where b_sno=d.a_sno
      and a_sno>d.a_sno
     )
    )q
```

*result:*

```
sno gn
7   1
14  2
15  3
```

**2.** use a `recursive cte` to find all related members in groups:

```
with recursive cte(sno,gn,path,cycle)as(
  select q.sno,
         row_number() over(order by q.sno) gn,
         array[q.sno],false
  from(
    select distinct d.a_sno sno
    from data d
    where not exists (
      select b_sno
      from data
      where b_sno=d.a_sno
      and a_sno>d.a_sno
     )
    )q
  union all
  select d.a_sno,c.gn,
         d.a_sno || c.path,
         d.a_sno=any(c.path)
  from data d
  join cte c on d.b_sno=c.sno 
  where not cycle
 )
 select distinct gn,sno from cte
 order by gn,sno
```

*Result:*

```
gn  sno
1   4
1   5
1   6
1   7
2   9
2   10
2   13
2   14
3   11
3   15
```

[here is **the demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/13cb0/3) of what I did.

Comment: Very smart query. I like it. I have come up with a somewhat similar solution, without redundant rows and `DISTINCT` steps.

Comment: I see you did it smarter, your cte does not need to a cycle flag and a path array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a start that may give some ideas on an approach. The recursive query starts with `a_sno` of each record and then tries to follow the path of `b_sno` until it reaches the end or forms a cycle. The path is represented by an array of `sno` integers.

The `unnest` function will break the array into rows, so a `sno` value mapped to the path array such as:

```
4, {6, 5, 4}
```

will be transformed to a row for each value in the array:

```
4, 6
4, 5
4, 4
```

The `array_agg` then reverses the operation by aggregating the values back into a path, but getting rid of the duplicates and ordering.

Now each `a_sno` is associated with a path and the path forms the grouping. `dense_rank` can be used to map the grouping (cluster) to a numeric.

```
SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT map ORDER BY map) AS cluster
      ,sno
  FROM ( WITH RECURSIVE x(sno, path, cycle) AS (
             SELECT a_sno, ARRAY[a_sno], false FROM  data
             UNION ALL
             SELECT b_sno, path || b_sno, b_sno = ANY(path)
               FROM data, x
               WHERE a_sno = x.sno
                 AND NOT cycle
         )
         SELECT sno, unnest(path) AS map FROM x ORDER BY 1
       ) y
  GROUP BY sno
  ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Output:

```
   cluster    | sno 
--------------+-----
 {4,5,6,7}    |   4
 {4,5,6,7}    |   5
 {4,5,6,7}    |   6
 {4,5,6,7}    |   7
 {9,10,13,14} |   9
 {9,10,13,14} |  10
 {9,10,13,14} |  13
 {9,10,13,14} |  14
 {11,15}      |  11
 {11,15}      |  15
(10 rows)
```

Wrap it one more time for the ranking:

```
SELECT dense_rank() OVER(order by cluster) AS rank
      ,sno
  FROM (
    SELECT array_agg(DISTINCT map ORDER BY map) AS cluster
          ,sno
      FROM ( WITH RECURSIVE x(sno, path, cycle) AS (
                 SELECT a_sno, ARRAY[a_sno], false FROM  data
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT b_sno, path || b_sno, b_sno = ANY(path)
                   FROM data, x
                   WHERE a_sno = x.sno
                     AND NOT cycle
             )
             SELECT sno, unnest(path) AS map FROM x ORDER BY 1
           ) y
      GROUP BY sno
      ORDER BY 1, 2
) z
```

Output:

```
 rank | sno 
------+-----
    1 |   4
    1 |   5
    1 |   6
    1 |   7
    2 |   9
    2 |  10
    2 |  13
    2 |  14
    3 |  11
    3 |  15
(10 rows)
```

Comment: It does the job, but with more than a few rows, this might get expensive.