# WITH RECURSIVE query to choose the longest paths

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query, directed-graph

I am new to `WITH RECURSIVE` in PostgreSQL. I have a reasonably standard recursive query that is following an adjacency list. If I have, for example:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
3 -> 5
5 -> 6
```

it produces:

```
1
1,2
1,2,3
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,5
1,2,3,5,6
```

What I would like is to have just:

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,5,6
```

But I can't see how to do this in Postgres. This would seem to be "choose the longest paths" or "choose the paths that are not contained in another path". I can probably see how to do this with a join on itself, but that seems quite inefficient.

An example query is:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(id, link, data, depth, path, cycle) AS (
   SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, 1, ARRAY[g.id], false
   FROM graph g
  UNION ALL
   SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, sg.depth + 1, path || g.id, g.id = ANY(path)
   FROM graph g, search_graph sg
   WHERE g.id = sg.link AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT * FROM search_graph;
```

Comment: Search for numbers that do not have children. Build from found childless numbers up.

Comment: BTW: your intended output `1,2,3,4 |
1,2,3,5,6` *cannot* exist, since each node only has one `link` field, and thus only one successor. ('3' has both '4' and '5' as successors.

Comment: Stupid user interface: I misclicked and marked Erwins comment as offensive :-)

Comment: The other question was ltree specific. That one I haven't got back to.  The answer below was helpful.

Comment: Here is a related answer to a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29738605/939860. Is your case "simple" as your demo suggest, less simple or an undirected graph where even cycles are possible?

Comment: I hope it will be helpful for future readers. It will not solve your Original Question, though. (see my comment above)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have a solution at your fingertips with `cycle`, just add a predicate at the end.

But adjust your break condition by one level, currently you are appending one node too many:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search AS (
   SELECT id, link, data, ARRAY[g.id] AS path, (link = id) AS cycle
   FROM   graph g
   WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT FROM graph WHERE link = g.id)

   UNION ALL
   SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, s.path || g.id, g.link = ANY(s.path)
   FROM   search s
   JOIN   graph g ON g.id = s.link
   WHERE  NOT s.cycle
   )
SELECT *
FROM   search
WHERE cycle;
-- WHERE cycle IS NOT FALSE;  -- alternative if link can be NULL
```

- Also including a start condition like [mentioned by @wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29805241/939860).
- Init condition for `cycle` is  `(link = id)`  to catch shortcut cycles. Not necessary if you have a `CHECK` constraint to disallow that in your table.
- The exact implementation depends on the missing details.
- This is assuming all graphs are terminated with a cycle or `link IS NULL` and there is a FK constraint from `link` to `id` in the same table.
  The exact implementation depends on missing details. If `link` is not actually a link (no referential integrity), you need to adapt ...

Comment: This is extremely helpful and very pretty solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the extra clause to the final query, like in:

```
WITH RECURSIVE search_graph(id, link, data, depth, path, cycle) AS (
   SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, 1, ARRAY[g.id], false
    FROM graph g
    -- BTW: you should add a START-CONDITION here, like:
    -- WHERE g.id = 1
    -- or even (to find ALL linked lists):
    -- WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 13
          -- FROM graph nx
          -- WHERE nx.link = g.id
          -- )
  UNION ALL
     SELECT g.id, g.link, g.data, sg.depth + 1, path || g.id, g.id = ANY(path)
    FROM graph g, search_graph sg
    WHERE g.id = sg.link AND NOT cycle
)
SELECT * FROM search_graph sg
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( -- <<-- extra condition
   SELECT 42 FROM graph nx
   WHERE nx.id = sg.link
    );
```

---

Do note that:

- the `not exists(...)` -clause tries to join *exactly* the same record as the second *leg* of the recursive union.
- So: they are mutually exclusive.
- if it *would* exist, it should have been *appended* to the "list" by the recursive query.

Comment: What if the results are '1,2,3,4' and '1,2,4,5'? Won't the first one be ignored although it's not a part of the other one?

Comment: No, the not exists-clause tries to join *exactly* the same record as the second "leg" of the recursive union. So: they are mutually exclusive. (if it would exist, it should have been appended to the "list")

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful, I was just thinking of a join which would be painful. And +1 for using 42.

Comment: maybe by using ltree; but the plain recursive query will always yield the partial results, too. (as you know, I know) @ErwinBrandstetter

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this should be considered as ugly join solution.

```
WITH recursive graph (child, parent) AS (
    SELECT 2, 1
    UNION
    SELECT 3, 2
    UNION
    SELECT 4, 2
    UNION
    SELECT 6, 5
    UNION
    SELECT 7, 6
    UNION
    SELECT 6, 7
),
paths (start, node, depth, path, has_cycle, terminated) AS (
    SELECT
        ARRAY[g1.parent],
        false,
        false
    FROM graph g1
    WHERE true
        AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM graph g2 WHERE g1.parent = g2.child)
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        p.path || g.child,
        g.child = ANY(p.path),
        g.parent is null AS terminated
    FROM paths p
    LEFT OUTER JOIN graph g ON g.parent = p.node
    WHERE NOT has_cycle
)
SELECT * from path WHERE terminated
;
```

So the trick is to use `terminated` column via using `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and then select only terminated paths.