# How to calculate a user's daily streak?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

### My goal

I'm trying to track and display a user's daily streak posting to my app, but struggling to write a query that works reliably and returns an accurate count.

### Some context

My app has a `prompt` and a `post` table. A user can submit one post for each prompt (the prompts are created daily, so one post per day, per user).

The `prompt` table, simplified, looks like this:

| id | dateKey | text |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20240101 | This is an example prompt. |
| 2 | 20240102 | Here is a second prompt. |

The `post` table, simplified, is something like:

| id | content | promptId | authorId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | This is my response to the prompt. | 1 | 90 |
| 51 | A second response to the same prompt. | 1 | 91 |

### Current query

I've tried a few different approaches to queries (using `PARTITION BY`, `dense_rank()` etc.) but could only get the user's longest streak. The query I had if you're interested:

```sql
select distinct on (p."authorId") count(distinct "dateKey"::date) as "streak"
from (select p.*,
      dense_rank() over (partition by p."authorId" order by "dateKey"::date) as seq
      from post p
      join prompt pt on p."promptId" = pt.id
     ) p
join prompt pt on p."promptId" = pt.id
where p."authorId" = 90
group by p."authorId", "dateKey"::date - seq * interval '1 day'
order by p."authorId", streak desc
```

This appears to work with the below data, but if you add a new "missed" prompt (which should reset the streak), this query would still return 2 (I think I understand why, but not sure how to correct it).

### What I need

I basically need something to start at the latest prompt, and go down the list until it finds a prompt with no post from that user.

For example, this joined data would have a streak of **2**:

| id | dateKey | text | postContent | authorId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 20240104 | This is an example prompt. | This is my response. | 90 |
| 2 | 20240103 | Here is a second prompt. | A second response. | 90 |
| 3 | 20240102 | A third prompt. | null | null |
| 4 | 20240101 | My fourth prompt. | A third response, but I missed a day. | 90 |

Functionality most important, but would be nice if it were performant too (`prompt` might have 1000 rows, `post` might have millions, and the `streak` might reach 1000).

I'm a bit lost with PostgreSQL's capabilities for things like this, so hopefully there's a simple solution out there!

Fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/11431

Comment: It would be instrumental to provide actual table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` script) with sample data as `INSERT` script. Or a fiddle to work with. And always disclose your version of Postgres, please. Also, start at the latest day or "today"?

Comment: Good call. Might be obsolete now, but here's a fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/11431

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single table with natural value progression there are simpler solutions. But for the combination of two tables with a (seemingly) arbitrary next `promptId` I expect a [recursive CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) to perform best:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
   SELECT CURRENT_DATE AS the_day, p."authorId" AS author_id
   FROM   prompt pt
   JOIN   post  p ON p."promptId" = pt.id
   WHERE  pt."dateKey" = CURRENT_DATE
   AND    p."authorId" = 90  -- your author here!
   
   UNION ALL
   SELECT c.the_day - 1, p."authorId"   -- assuming no gaps in prompt!
   FROM   cte   c
   JOIN   prompt pt ON pt."dateKey" = c.the_day - 1
   JOIN   post  p  ON p."promptId" = pt.id
   WHERE  p."authorId" = c.author_id
   )
SELECT count(*)
FROM   cte;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NgKgjITE)

Absolutely requires index support to be fast.
*Ideally*, one index on `prompt("dateKey", id)`, and one on `post("authorId", "promptId")`.

Assuming ...

- ... we query for one given user,
- ... we start "today",
- ... no gaps in prompt - exactly one entry per day,
- ... `prompt."dateKey"` is type `date` (as it should be).

Related:

- [WITH RECURSIVE query to choose the longest paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29804763/with-recursive-query-to-choose-the-longest-paths/29808669#29808669)

#### DB design

**If** there is at most one prompt per day, consider using the date (data type `date`!) as PK in table `prompt` and FK in table `post`. Allows for much simpler queries. See:

- [Select longest continuous sequence](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35389/3684)

Comment: Thank you, seems to work great. What are the concerns with a gap in prompts? If a day was missed, how would this query behave (and is there a way to account for that)? Additionally, I'm wondering if it's possible to give the user 1 day leniency for the streak? So that it doesn't appear to reset to 0 once the day ticks over. How can I give them until the end of day before it counts as "broken"? Thanks again, will be sure to add the indexes and review keys.

Comment: @JayAdra: The task for missing days is undefined. This query terminates the streak. Leniency:  just start with "yesterday" instead of "today".

Comment: That's fair, missing days shouldn't be a problem anyway. As for starting with "yesterday", this would mean the streak wouldn't update if they posted "today", until the day ticks over to tomorrow. I'll play around and see if I can get a condition in there for "today" only.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like island and gap problem and gap problem.

I have created query for single `authorid` (`p.authorId = 90`) as asked in the question. You can remove the join condition to get the data for all the `authorIds`.

Solution is to use the window functions as follows:

```
select authorId, max(sm) from
(select t.*, 
        sum(case when prev_promptId is null then 1 end ) over (partition by p.authorId order by "dateKey"::date) as sm 
  from (select pt.*, p.*, 
               lag(p.promptId) over (partition by p.authorId order by "dateKey"::date) as prev_promptId
          from prompt pt
          left join post p on p.promptId = pt.id and p.authorId = 90) t ) t
group by authorId;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions. I've been playing around with your query but can't get it to work. There seems to be some syntax errors with `sum(case when is null then 1 end )`, but even correcting those (and table/column refs), I get incorrect streak values. 

I'll keep trying, but I don't think this query achieves what I need. Appreciate your time though.

Comment: Yes, It should be `sum(case when prev_promptId  is null then 1 end )`, I have updated the answer