# Combining 3 SELECT statements to output 1 table

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, union-all

I have three queries with results.

Query 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, work.clientid, ROUND ((CAST (AVG(current_lawn_price) AS numeric) / CAST (AVG((((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_finish)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_finish))) - ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_start)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_start))) AS numeric)) / 1, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM work
JOIN timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN client USING (clientid)
WHERE employeeid = 1 AND workid < 557 AND workid > 188
GROUP BY employeeid, clientid ORDER BY clientid ASC;

employeeid | clientid | under_over_1
------------+----------+--------------
          1 |        3 |         0.54
          1 |        4 |         0.47
          1 |        6 |         0.45
          1 |        7 |         0.59
          . |        . |           .
          . |        . |           .
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, work.clientid, ROUND ((CAST (AVG(current_lawn_price) AS numeric) / CAST (AVG((((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_finish)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_finish))) - ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_start)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_start))) AS numeric)) / 1.31666666666667, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM work
JOIN timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN client USING (clientid)
WHERE employeeid = 2
GROUP BY employeeid, clientid ORDER BY clientid ASC;

 employeeid | clientid | under_over_1
------------+----------+--------------
          2 |        2 |         1.01
          2 |        3 |         0.21
          2 |        4 |         0.71
          2 |        6 |         0.68
          . |        . |           .
          . |        . |           .
```

Query: 3

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, work.clientid, ROUND ((CAST (AVG(current_lawn_price) AS numeric) / CAST (AVG((((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_finish)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_finish))) - ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_start)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_start))) AS numeric)) / 1.31666666666667, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM work
JOIN timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN client USING (clientid)
WHERE employeeid = 3
GROUP BY employeeid, clientid ORDER BY clientid ASC;

 employeeid | clientid | under_over_1
------------+----------+--------------
          3 |        4 |         0.70
          3 |        6 |         0.54
          3 |        7 |         1.03
          3 |       11 |         0.74
          . |        . |           .
          . |        . |           .
```

I want to output one table with the result of all three queries such as (I am sorry but I have to write more here so I can submit this post. I hope this is enough;-)):

```
employeeid | clientid | under_over_1
------------+----------+--------------
          1 |        3 |         0.54
          1 |        4 |         0.47
          1 |        6 |         0.45
          1 |        7 |         0.59
          . |        . |           .
          . |        . |           .
          2 |        2 |         1.01
          2 |        3 |         0.21
          2 |        4 |         0.71
          2 |        6 |         0.68
          . |        . |           .
          . |        . |           .
          3 |        4 |         0.70
          3 |        6 |         0.54
          3 |        7 |         1.03
          3 |       11 |         0.74
          . |        . |           .
          . |        . |           .
```

I tried `UNION ALL` as in

```
SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, work.clientid, ROUND ((CAST (AVG(current_lawn_price) AS numeric) / CAST (AVG((((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_finish)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_finish))) - ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_start)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_start))) AS numeric)) / 1, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM work
JOIN timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN client USING (clientid)
WHERE employeeid = 1 AND workid < 557 AND workid > 188
GROUP BY employeeid, clientid ORDER BY clientid ASC

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, work.clientid, ROUND ((CAST (AVG(current_lawn_price) AS numeric) / CAST (AVG((((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_finish)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_finish))) - ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_start)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_start))) AS numeric)) / 1.31666666666667, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM work
JOIN timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN client USING (clientid)
WHERE employeeid = 3
GROUP BY employeeid, clientid ORDER BY clientid ASC

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT employeeid, work.clientid, ROUND ((CAST (AVG(current_lawn_price) AS numeric) / CAST (AVG((((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_finish)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_finish))) - ((EXTRACT(HOUR FROM job_start)*60) + EXTRACT(MIN FROM job_start))) AS numeric)) / 1.31666666666667, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM work
JOIN timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN client USING (clientid)
WHERE employeeid = 2
GROUP BY employeeid, clientid ORDER BY clientid ASC;
```

However, I get the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "UNION"
> LINE 7: UNION ALL
> ```

I am not sure why this is wrong or whether `UNION ALL` is the right approach here. Anyone have a clue?

Comment: I wonder if adding `()` around the individual queries would have helped.

Comment: Assuming `/ 1` in your first query is supposed to be `/ 1.31666666666667` like in the others.

Comment: That is correct. I cannot use epoch as the type is time without time zone. Such as 12:34:00, 04:05:00, 00:12:00 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate cause for the error is, quoting [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION):

> (`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` can be attached to a subexpression if it is
> **enclosed in parentheses**. Without parentheses, these clauses will be
> taken to apply to the result of the `UNION`, not to its right-hand input
> expression.)

Bold emphasis mine.

So, as suggested by @wilx, enclosing each `SELECT` in parentheses would fix *that*.

But there is more.

#### Merge into single query

```sql
SELECT employeeid, work.clientid    -- no DISTINCT
     , ROUND ((AVG(current_lawn_price)
             / AVG(extract(epoch FROM job_finish - job_start)))::numeric / 79, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM   work
JOIN   timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN   client    USING (clientid)
WHERE (employeeid IN (1, 2) OR
       employeeid = 3
   AND workid < 557
   AND workid > 188)
GROUP  BY employeeid, clientid 
ORDER  BY CASE employeeid
            WHEN 1 THEN 1
            WHEN 2 THEN 3
            WHEN 3 THEN 2
          END
        , clientid;
```

Merge the 3 `SELECT` queries.

Remove the redundant `DISTINCT`. That's an expensive no-op after `GROUP BY`.

Instead of extracting hours and minutes from both begin and end timestamps etc., compute the `interval` by plain subtraction (works with `timestamp` or `time` values alike) and extract the `epoch` from it. Gives you the number of seconds. Divide by 60 and you got the number of minutes much faster. **79** being the result of ***60 * 1.31666666666667***, accordingly.

The [manual about extracting `epoch`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT):

> For `timestamp with time zone` values, the number of seconds since
> 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC (can be negative); for `date` and `timestamp`
> values, the number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 local time;
> **for `interval` values, the total number of seconds in the interval**

Bold emphasis mine.

Since this removes `UNION ALL`, the parentheses mentioned at the top are not needed any more.

The `CASE` expression makes up for the mixed order in `employeeid`, like [sticky bit provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59348832/939860).

#### If queries cannot be merged

If, for some reason, you can't or won't merge the three original `SELECT` queries, do this instead:

```sql
(  -- parentheses required
SELECT employeeid, work.clientid    -- no DISTINCT !
     , ROUND ((AVG(current_lawn_price)
             / AVG(extract(epoch FROM job_finish - job_start)))::numeric / 79, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM   work
JOIN   timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN   client    USING (clientid)
WHERE  employeeid = 1
AND    workid < 557 
AND    workid > 188
GROUP  BY clientid  -- no need to GROUP BY employeeid while filtering single value
ORDER  BY clientid
)

UNION ALL
(
SELECT employeeid, work.clientid
     , ROUND ((AVG(current_lawn_price)
             / AVG(extract(epoch FROM job_finish - job_start)))::numeric / 79, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM   work
JOIN   timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN   client    USING (clientid)
WHERE  employeeid = 3
GROUP  BY clientid
ORDER  BY clientid
)

UNION ALL
(
SELECT employeeid, work.clientid
     , ROUND ((AVG(current_lawn_price)
             / AVG(extract(epoch FROM job_finish - job_start)))::numeric / 79, 2) AS under_over_1
FROM   work
JOIN   timesheet USING (date_linkid)
JOIN   client    USING (clientid)
WHERE  employeeid = 2
GROUP  BY clientid
ORDER  BY clientid
);
-- no outer ORDER BY required
```

Keep `ORDER BY` per `SELECT` and add parentheses to fix the syntax. `UNION ALL` (as opposed to `UNION`) simply appends results preserving the order of individual `SELECT`s. This should be ***cheaper*** than ordering the whole set *after* `UNION ALL`. And you did want to keep using queries individual `SELECT` queries "as is" ...

Most of the other advice above applies accordingly.

***Aside:*** make it a habit to use table aliases and table-qualify all columns in queries joining multiple tables. Much more robust against later changes and easier to read / debug.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. I went with your first select statement. I had to modify it due to the following error: 
```ERROR:  function round(double precision, integer) does not exist
LINE 2:      , ROUND (AVG(current_lawn_price)::numeric
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.``` When I used my original ROUND(.... it worked fine so thanks.

Comment: @ChristianHick: I fixed the expression by casting the result of the division to `numeric`. If you want to do the division in `numeric` (slower, more precise), cast both averages to `numeric` instead.

Comment: I ran the command with your fix. It works without error. I am however not able to use epoch as type is time without time zone (see comment above) so I left it as I had it in my query but changed CAST() AS numeric to ::numeric. Works fine.

Comment: @ChristianHick: `::numeric` is just shorthand syntax, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13676871/939860. And my expression should just work for data type `time`. See: *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1ed03f8bbc344e1631d7b4f6de19e11e)*. Substantially simpler and faster. Just sayin.

Comment: If I run your query (the first one) as is, all rows for under_over_1 = 0.00. So epoch does not work. job_finish and job_start are not timestamps, they are hours and minute columns, e.g.: 00:23:00, 01:11:00, 25:12:00 etc. There are not seconds for epoch to draw on.

Comment: You said `type is time without time zone`. But `25:12:00` is not a valid `time` Would work as `interval`. Please remember to disclose your actual table definition (`CREATE TABLE` statement) next time.

Answer (score 1):

Remove all the `ORDER BY`s. Then use the resulting query as a derived table. To retain the order you presumably want, you can then use a `CASE` expression to map the `employeeid` to and integer determining the order:

```
SELECT x.employeeid,
       x.clientid,
       x.under_over_1
       FROM (<your UNION ALL query without the ORDER BYs>) x
       ORDER BY CASE x.employeeid
                  WHEN 1 THEN
                    1
                  WHEN 2 THEN
                    3
                  WHEN 3 THEN
                    2
                END,
                x.clientid;
```

Comment: I am afraid the CASE statement didn't work. I get error message:
```ERROR:  invalid UNION/INTERSECT/EXCEPT ORDER BY clause
LINE 20: GROUP BY employeeid, clientid ORDER BY CASE employeeid
                                                ^
DETAIL:  Only result column names can be used, not expressions or functions.
HINT:  Add the expression/function to every SELECT, or move the UNION into a FROM clause.
```

Comment: @ChristianHick: Yeah right, sorry. You'd need to use a derived table additionally for such expressions to work. I edited the answer.