# Calculate difference of multiple highest and lowest column values

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table like this:

```
id | name | salary
------------------
1  | guy1 | 1000
2  | guy2 | 750
3  | guy3 | 400
4  | guy4 | 1000
5  | guy5 | 925
6  | guy6 | 900
```

I need to take the highest salaries (in this case 2 * 1000) and the lowest  (in this case 1 * 400), and return the difference between highest and lowest calculated like this:

**1000 * 2 - 400 * 1 = 1600**

```
difference
----------
1600
```

I tried to filter the table where salaries are highest and lowest but failed.

If the table is empty the result should be 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres 13 adds the **`WITH TIES`** clause to include all peers of the nth row:

- [Get top row(s) with highest value, with ties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178114/get-top-rows-with-highest-value-with-ties/63184287#63184287)

If you have an index on `salary`, this will be **as fast as it gets**. Much faster than involving window functions:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(sum(salary), 0) AS diff
FROM  (
   (  -- parentheses required
   SELECT salary
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY salary DESC
   FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
   )
   UNION ALL
   (
   SELECT salary * -1
   FROM   tbl
   ORDER  BY salary
   FETCH  FIRST 1 ROWS WITH TIES
   )
   ) sub;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ca501a3439da0906470b9f2c79cb38de)*

Postgres can take the first and last values from an index on `(salary)` directly. Quasi-instantaneous result, no matter how big the table might be.

`COALESCE()` to get `0` instead of `NULL` when the table is empty.

Why the extra parentheses? [The manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-UNION):

> (`ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` can be attached to a subexpression if it is
> enclosed in parentheses. Without parentheses, these clauses will be
> taken to apply to the result of the `UNION`, not to its right-hand input
> expression.)

See:

- [Create a unique index on a non-unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171623/create-a-unique-index-on-a-non-unique-column/29172960#29172960)
- [Combining 3 SELECT statements to output 1 table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59348755/combining-3-select-statements-to-output-1-table/59349080#59349080)

This is assuming `salary` is `NOT NULL`, else append `NULLS LAST` to the descending order. See:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select
  (select sum(salary) from t where salary = (select max(salary) from t))
  -
  (select sum(salary) from t where salary = (select min(salary) from t));
```

Result:

```
1600
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uxLwXG3JBKJrtFPKGoCgU/0).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It's almost right, expect the `count(*) * sum(salary)`. I changed it to `count(*) + sum(salary)` and it gave me almost the right answer, insteed of 1600 it gives me 1601. And in case of empty table it should output 0.

Comment: @MikeEhrmantraut - Fixed. As you can see, the answer was actually simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `dense_rank` to find the lowest and the highest salary, and then self join those results, sum them, and subtract:

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE sal_desc WHEN 1 THEN salary END) - 
       SUM(CASE sal_asc WHEN 1 THEN salary END)
FROM   (SELECT salary, 
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary ASC)  AS sal_asc,
               DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY salary DESC) AS sal_desc
        FROM   mytable) t
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to aggregate twice:

```
select sum(case when seqnum_desc = 1 then sum_salary
                else - sum_salary
           end) as diff
from (select salary, sum(salary) as sum_salary,
             row_number() over (order by salary asc) as seqnum_asc,
             row_number() over (order by salary desc) as seqnum_desc
      from t
      group by salary
     ) t
where 1 in (seqnum_asc, seqnum_desc)
```