# UNION works with CTE, but not without?

Tags: sql, postgresql, union, greatest-n-per-group

I'm using PostgreSQL 11.12.

I have this query:

```
select first_name, length(first_name)
from db_employee
where length(first_name) = 
(select max(length(first_name)) from db_employee)
order by 1 
limit 1
union
select first_name, length(first_name)
from db_employee
where length(first_name) = 
(select min(length(first_name)) from db_employee)
order by 1 
limit 1
```

and when I run it I get this error:

```
syntax error at or near "union"
```

If I use CTE it works:

```
with cte1 as
(select first_name, length(first_name)
from db_employee
where length(first_name) = 
(select max(length(first_name)) from db_employee)
order by 1 
limit 1),

cte2 as
(select first_name, length(first_name)
from db_employee
where length(first_name) = 
(select min(length(first_name)) from db_employee)
order by 1 
limit 1)

select * from cte1
union
select * from cte2;
```

Why does the first query result in syntax error?  Is it possible to get it to work without using CTE?

Comment: Does this work for you? It is for MySQL but worth a try. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415328/combining-union-and-limit-operations-in-mysql-query

Comment: Sure does.  Feel free to comment below so you can get credit.

Comment: Is `UNION` intentional? I.e., do you want to merge both rows if both are the same? Typically, that shouldn't be a thing, and you really want `UNION ALL` ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To include a `LIMIT` clause per `SELECT` in a `UNION` query, you must add **parentheses**. Like:

```sql
(  -- !
SELECT first_name, length(first_name)
FROM   db_employee
WHERE  length(first_name) = (SELECT max(length(first_name)) FROM db_employee)
ORDER  BY 1
LIMIT  1
) -- !
UNION
( -- !
SELECT first_name, length(first_name)
FROM   db_employee
WHERE  length(first_name) = (SELECT min(length(first_name)) FROM db_employee)
ORDER  BY 1
LIMIT  1
) -- !
```

Related:

- [Calculate difference of multiple highest and lowest column values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048998/calculate-difference-of-multiple-highest-and-lowest-column-values/65049876#65049876)

That said, your query can be optimized. Use instead:

```sql
(
SELECT first_name, length(first_name)
FROM   db_employee
ORDER  BY length(first_name) DESC NULLS LAST, first_name
LIMIT  1
)
UNION ALL  -- my guess
(
SELECT first_name, length(first_name)
FROM   db_employee
ORDER  BY length(first_name), first_name
LIMIT  1
);
```

Subtle difference: this does not completely exclude rows with `first_name IS NULL`, but that only shows if all rows have `first_name IS NULL`.

About `NULLS LAST`:

- [Sort by column ASC, but NULL values first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/sort-by-column-asc-but-null-values-first/9511492#9511492)

Comment: Using parenthesis makes sense.  I thought of using UNION (and not UNION ALL) because if the names are all the same length, then min/max length is same (granted this is corner case).  So you want to remove duplicates.  Did I miss something ?

Comment: All names with the same length is an exotic corner case. And nothing bad happens, you just get the same row twice. I would take the cheaper `UNION ALL`. Unimportant for the query at hand, just a common anti-pattern. Stripping the additional `SELECT` actually matters for performance.

Comment: Sounds good, I will do UNION ALL.  Last one.  I notice you're sorting by length.  Are you assuming there is an index on name and length?  Otherwise sorting is expensive ie O(n log n)

Comment: `ORDER BY length(first_name) LIMIT 1` is no more expensive than `(select max(length(first_name)) from db_employee)` - typically slightly cheaper, even. But my query only needs a single scan. Compare performance to see the proof. Each can profit from an expression index on `(length(first_name))`, or even a multicolumn index on `(length(first_name), first_name)`, but always weigh cost and benefit of a tailored index.

Answer (score 0):

just put both the sql parts in separate brackets and keep union outside.

```
    (select first_name, length(first_name)
    from db_employee
    where length(first_name) = 
    (select max(length(first_name)) from db_employee)
    order by 1
    limit 1)
    union
    (select first_name, length(first_name)
    from db_employee
    where length(first_name) = 
    (select min(length(first_name)) from db_employee)
    order by 1
    limit 1);
```

another way of doing the same thing:

```
    select * from (
    select first_name, l_fname
    ,row_number() over (order by l_fname) rn_min
    ,row_number() over (order by l_fname desc) rn_max
    from(
    select first_name,length(first_name) l_fname from db_employee
    ) A
    ) b where (rn_min = 1 or rn_max = 1);
```